# Get bytes from a stream of a URL http request that includes delayed data from an ajax call

Tags: c#, http, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I have a web page which once loaded triggers an ajax call to get additional data which can take a few seconds.  I want to be able to do a request to do a GET request to the webpage url and access the stream of the response as it arrives including the data returned by the ajax call.

I'm at a loss at what to try next.

The code below gets the webpage as a stream but it doesn't get the data which is returned by the ajax call. I'm using C# .Net framework 4.5.2

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

namespace HttpWebRequestTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HttpWebRequest req;
            HttpWebResponse res = null;

            try
            {
                req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(
                        "http://localhost/WebApp/");
                res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
                Stream stream = res.GetResponseStream();

                byte[] data = new byte[8096];
                int read;
                while ((read = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    Process(data, read);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (res != null)
                    res.Close();
            }
            Console.In.Read();
        }

        private static void Process(byte[] data, int read)
        {
            Console.Out.Write(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(data));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The GetResponse gets all data in one chunk.  If the data is not in one chunk you are using http1.1. [http 1.0 (stream mode) or http 1.1 chunk mode] Adding             req.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10; will get data in one chunk (stream mode)

Comment: WebClient utility is probably way better for these types of tasks.

Comment: All you're going to get is the JavaScript to make the AJAX request, but it will never be executed. If you want the data from the AJAX call then you'll need to make a separate call to *that* URL. `HttpWebRequest` is not a web browser.

Comment: Hi Dan, you're bang on of course.  Thanks.